# Prove that for any fixed non-negative random variable $X$, $\lim\limits_{n→∞}\frac1nE\left(\frac1X I_{\{X>1/n\}}\right) =0$

Tags: limits, expectation, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Show $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}E\left(\frac{1}{X} I_{\{X>1/n\}}\right) = 0.$$

I am totally lost on this problem. Any hint or reference to study will be greatly appreciated.